# Parsing secrets from AWS secrets manager using AWS cli

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

I am retrieving secrets I have stored in AWS secrets manager with the AWS cli like this:

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id secrets
```

Which returns

```
arn:aws:secretsmanager<ID>:secret:my_secrets <number> my_secrets {"API_KEY":"ABCDEFGHI"}       <UUID string>
VERSIONSTAGES   AWSCURRENT
```

Does anyone know how I only get the secret ("API_KEY": "ABCDEFGHI")?
I need to move these secrets to my register-task-definition environment variables. The best way would be to store them in a file and delete it after us or store them in variable. It is running on a linux machine.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Use the `--query` option of the CLI to extract just the secret.

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id secrets --query SecretString --output text
```

Comment: Is this no longer working? every secret is null for me

Comment: Ah `SecretString` selectes the entire secret string, it is not used to match a secret key

Comment: @caleb Just running the command resulted in that error or w -query did it work?

Comment: Came to a wrong place but found an answer (`--output text`) :)

Answer (score 41):

`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id secrets| jq --raw-output '.SecretString' | jq -r .API_KEY`

using jq you can print.

Comment: jq is not a standard util

Comment: And if your secret has a dash, you can use:
`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id my-secret --query SecretString --output text | jq '."my-secret"'`

Comment: Correction, to remove quotes in addition to making it work for a secret with a dash:
`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id my-secret --query SecretString --output text | jq -r '."my-secret"'`

Answer (score 30):

Small addition to helloV answer. You can add the output parameter `text` to remove the quotes.

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value \
   --secret-id secrets \
   --query SecretString \
   --output text
```

Answer (score 13):

If your secret will only have one key/pair value, and you only want the value to be printed out, and you don't want to rely on your system having jq installed first, you can do:

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id secrets --query SecretString --output text | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d \"}
```

Comment: you're missing a `"\"` before the last `}`, like `tr -d \"\}`

Comment: @GwenM not needed on GNU/Bash

Comment: ah yeah you might be right, I was using ZSH on mac

Comment: a good answer which doesn't require jq

Answer (score 11):

So I faced a bit of trouble in extracting what I needed, the value for my two variables that I stored in SecretsManager. So here is what worked for me.

NOTE: It's an example from the AWS SecretsManager doc.

## I ran this

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id MyTestDatabaseSecret --version-stage AWSPREVIOUS
```

## The response of this query is:

```
{
  "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:123456789012:secret:MyTestDatabaseSecret-a1b2c3",
  "Name": "MyTestDatabaseSecret",
  "VersionId": "EXAMPLE1-90ab-cdef-fedc-ba987EXAMPLE",
  "SecretString": "{\n  \"username\":\"david\",\n  \"password\":\"BnQw&XDWgaEeT9XGTT29\"\n}\n",
  "VersionStages": [
    "AWSPREVIOUS"
  ],
  "CreatedDate": 1523477145.713
}
```

## Now I want to get the value of username or password to be precise

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id MyTestDatabaseSecret --version-stage AWSPREVIOUS | jq --raw-output .SecretString | jq -r ."password"
```

## Output

```
BnQw&XDWgaEeT9XGTT29
```

Comment: I want to list all secrets and then get all values and run grep against it

Comment: > aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id *         is not working for me

Comment: what is the error message? Do you have access rights to all? Are you passing the version number in your query? Instead of using * wild character, can you make a list of secret-id and then try to run a loop. First, try to run it for 10 odd secrets and then check to scale it up.

Comment: https://github.com/ashishkarpe/scripts_aws_cli/blob/main/find_secrets_values.sh have written script which worked for me thanks

Answer (score 11):

When you have multiple secret and you get json return, you can use get the exact value of password by using

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <secret_bucket_name> | jq --raw-output '.SecretString' | jq -r .key_for_password
```

Comment: jq is json utility for shell command. it helps to parse the Json and pull the attribute from the file.

Comment: this is a copy-paste of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52921217/4212158

Comment: In my case, The password has '&' symbol and is converted to '\u0026'. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 8):

All answers working but require 3rd party integration ( mainly `jq` ). the following bash command grabs the relevant Value without any other 3rd party solution -

```bash
SECRET_ARN=arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:123456:secret:/test
SECRET_KEY=DB_PASSWORD
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value \ 
  --secret-id $SECRET_ARN \ 
  --query SecretString \
  --output text | grep -o '"$SECRET_KEY":"[^"]*' |  grep -o '[^"]*$'
```

Comment: The answered marked as the correct one does not require jq: aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id secrets --query SecretString --output text

Comment: The marked answer gets all secret values. my example grabs a specific value based on a secret key.

Comment: This works great for extracting the value of a single key in a simple key/value pair JSON object stored in Secrets Manager.  Thank you @AmitBaranes

Answer (score 7):

Lots of answers here depend on `jq`. If you don't want to install any other dependencies, you can use a `python3` one-liner:

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value \
   --output text \
   --query SecretString \
   --secret-id my-secret-name \
| python3 -c 'import json, sys; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["my-secret-key"])'
```

Based on [helloV's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50916032/9636).

Comment: Thank you for this. You can also assign this to a variable this way: `SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value \
   --output text \
   --query SecretString \
   --secret-id my-secret-name \
| python3 -c 'import json, sys; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["my-secret-key"])')`

Answer (score 1):

> PowerShell solution without Jq

```
$a = aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --region <region> --secret-id <secret-name>  | ConvertFrom-Json
```

$a all json converted to objects type

**Output**

```
ARN           : xxxxxx
Name          : postgxxx
VersionId     : fxxxx-xx-x-xx
SecretString  : {"key":"value","key2":"value"}
VersionStages : {xxxxx}
CreatedDate   : xxxxx.xx
```

---

```
$b = $a.SecretString | ConvertFrom-Json
```

**Output**

```
key : value
key2 : value
```

---

```
$b.key

**Output** 
value
```

Answer (score 1):

## Script to List all available AWS secrets to a /tmp/name.text and find specific secret values from it

## Note needs AWS CLI configure to run this script successfully

```
#!/bin/bash

aws secretsmanager list-secrets | grep  "Name" | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '"' | sed 's/,/ /g' > /tmp/name.text

for line in `cat /tmp/name.text`
do

echo $line >> /tmp/secrets-values.txt

aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id "$line" | grep "XYZ" >>  /tmp/secrets-values.txt
done
```

Comment: Did it work? You tested. If yes, then great. :)

Comment: yes I tested it and it worked

Answer (score 1):

In the vein of "... without `jq`" answers, here's one for `node` users. (requires modern bash and nodejs, could easily be rewritten to just use sh by using an `echo |` instead of the cleaner `<<<`)

```sh
SECRET_ARN="..."
REGION=us-east-1

SECRET_BLOB=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --region="$REGION" --output=text --query SecretString --secret-id "$SECRET_ARN")

MY_VALUE=$(node -pe 'JSON.parse(require("fs").readFileSync("/dev/stdin").toString()).myKey' <<< "$SECRET_BLOB")

MY_OTHER_VALUE=$(node -pe 'JSON.parse(require("fs").readFileSync("/dev/stdin").toString()).myOtherKey' <<< "$SECRET_BLOB")
```

If you need to pull multiple values from the secret, you'll want to cache the json blob in an env var. If you only need a single value though:

```sh
MY_VALUE=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --region="$REGION" --output=text --query SecretString --secret-id "$SECRET_ARN" | node -pe 'JSON.parse(require("fs").readFileSync("/dev/stdin").toString()).myKey' <<< "$SECRET_BLOB")
```

Answer (score 1):

I see many JQ examples but Powershell has a pretty awesome integration with AWS.  This is the way I do it in Powershell:

Your JSON value

> {"API_KEY":"ABCDEFGHI"}

```
$aws_secret = Get-SECSecretValue -SecretId my_secrets
$mysecret = $aws_secret.SecretString | ConvertFrom-Json
$myapikey = $mysecret.API_KEY
$newsecret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $myapikey -AsPlainText -Force
```

The value from the secret manager is a JSON which Powershell can natively convert into a type of array that you can reference. I convert it back into a secure string under the assumption its a secret and you want to pass it in. The code above should work for you.  Let me know if you run into any issues with the code I provided.

Answer (score -3):

Use this to get just the value of the secret key. Make sure to fill in your secert ID and the key of the secret:

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <yourSecretID> | jq '.SecretString' | tail -c +2 | head -c -2 | tr -d '\' | jq .<YourSecretKey>
```